# jQuery and sharedworkers

Tags: jquery, shared-worker

Am I right in saying that jQuery can't be used inside a [Sharedworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker).  Shared workers operate outside of a browser tab and don't have access to window/document (that I'm aware off) so I don't think jQuery will work as again I think it needs access to the window object.

The above being the case - is there any methods or structure that can be used to modify the jQuery code so that it can be loaded without access to the window object?

Looking at the jQuery code I see this -

```
( function( global, factory ) {

"use strict";

if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {

    // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
    // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
    // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
    // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
    // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
    // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
    // See ticket #14549 for more info.
    module.exports = global.document ?
        factory( global, true ) :
        function( w ) {
            if ( !w.document ) {
                throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
            }
            return factory( w );
        };
} else {
    factory( global );
}

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
} )( typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
```

So without access to window or document, it can't work?

Comment: What is it that you need to do? jQuery is primarily a DOM manipulation library. Without a DOM, there's not a lot of point to it...

Comment: aha - I was just waiting for that comment... I'm using a library that isn't public and has exact same loading syntax as jquery.  I'm wanting to use that in a shared worker :)

Comment: Then post a question quoting the relevant parts of that library's load (anonymized and such, but with the structure unchanged) rather than asking about a library you don't actually want to use.

Comment: I can't, I really can't. But its the exact same - so if it can be done for jQuery then it can be done for the other library.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can anonymize and preserve the structure. But the answer is probably: If the library says it requires `document`, like the quoted jQuery code does and which you say is "exact same", then of course you can't use it without a `document.`

Comment: Sorry but I can't - as much as it seems like a crazy thing to say some times its not do-able.
Lets just say that the library uses the same loading mechanism of loading as jQuery (as highlighted in the code snippet - change the word jQuery for Foo if you wish) but not all its functions require the use of the DOM.

Comment: So the question remains the same - is there any way to use jQuery in a shared worker. If a method in jQuery didn't require the window or document is there a way to use it?